# Bitwise not "~" in PHP not working, "Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in ..."

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

PHP Doc (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) clearly states:

```
~ $a    Not  Bits that are set in $a are not set, and vice versa.
```

So why am I getting a fatal error when trying to run the following line?

```
~ $noResults;
```

TIA

Comment: are you are assigning the result to something? eg $noResults = ~$noResults;

Comment: ThiefMaster is correct , its the wrong type. Doh PHP!

Comment: @bumperbox - no, you don't have to for the ~ operator.

Comment: What datatype is $noResults.... you're not trying this on a resource are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because `$noResults` is not an integer (or string, but that's just because of implicit typecasting).

Comment: ~ will work on datatypes other than integer... try setting $noResults to 'A' and then ~$noResults will give ¾

Answer (score 1):

`~` will work on numbers and strings, couldn't get it working on objects and arrays.

AND the variable to negate MUST be set.

```
 echo ~ $a;  // won't work
```

whereas

```
$a = '';
echo ~ $a;  // will work
```

and

```
$a; echo ~$a; // will work too.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems with it :

```
$a = 5;
$a = ~ $a;
echo $a; // -6
```

Are you sure `$noResults` is an integer ?